# To train my self

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I am writing a letter of motivation and I wrote the following paragraph:

*My interest in optics begun at the beginning of my physics bachelor studies and it has been growing since then. Due to this interest, I started **to train myself** in optics-related topics. In brief, my experience includes an internship ...*

I am wondering if **to train myself** is the right verb to use in this context or if there are other verbs in English that better convey the idea.

Comment: did you teach yourself or did you begin to take courses?

Comment: I didn't teach myself, instead I did an internship in a company, I participated in a summer research program and I did my bachelor thesis in optics. I want to use "train myself" to refer to this activities, and this is why I am not sure of its usage. @MarkHubbard

Comment: "My interest in optics **started** at the beginning of my physics bachelor studies. **Since then I have trained myself in optics and related subjects.** My experience includes an internship with a company, I participated in a summer research program, and I did my bachelor thesis in optics."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think the idea is better expressed in this way. @MarkHubbard

Comment: Mark's edit is very good. Perhaps just 'trained' not 'trained myself' matches "I didn't teach myself" better. Remember that Spanish may use a reflexive verb (se habla) where English does not need it. Retaining 'myself' may not be the best translation. Another way to go is 'delved into optics...'

Comment: '… to train myself…' is in no way ungrammatical but it's quite unusual.

'… to teach myself…' would sound more natural.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original sentence.  There are other ways to phrase it, but no real reason other than personal preference to pick one vs another.

Comment: VTC as writing advice.

Comment: "train myself" sounds as though you read books and set up an optics lab in your garage and worked by yourself.  That is, you learned it all by yourself.  I suggest:  "Since then I have worked in optics and related subjects.  My experience includes....."

Comment: Due to this interest, I started to learn about optics.  Or: Due to this interest, I set about learning what I could about optics.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-study** ([here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-study))

> Due to this interest, I started to *self-study* optics-related topics.

This is probably what you were looking for, but, on a whim, I also might suggest dropping the verb altogether, in favor of a much more interesting word:

**Autodidact** ([here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autodidact)) or **Automath** ([here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Automath))

> Due to this interest, I became an *autodidact* in optics-related topics.
>
> Due to this interest, I became an *automath* for optics-related topics.

Comment: Beware using fancy words in a mundane context.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> My interest in optics begun at the beginning of my physics bachelor
>   studies and it has been growing since then. Due to this interest, I
>   started to train myself in optics-related topics. In brief, my
>   experience includes an internship ...

You note in comments that you're not talking about teaching yourself--so you don't want to use "train myself."  You might want to say "I started to focus on optics-related topics."

Also "begun at the beginning of" is a little awkward.  *begun* should be *began*.  It might be enough to say "My interest in optics began with my physics bachelor studies"